# Excite hydrogen with lower frequency photon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, atomic-physics

Suppose we have a photons with energies  less that the one to excite the hydrogen atom. If the hydrogen atom is  scattered by these photon it gains energy.
Can we excite the hydrogen atom by this process?

Comment: What do you mean by "the hydrogen atom is scattered by these photons"? Do you mean its movement is deflected? If you only ask about the photon getting absorbed by the atom you might find this question useful: [Energy conservation if photon absorbed below resonance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166130/)

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/601846/2451

Answer (score 1):

You already asked this question here and got an answer: [Absorption cross section for photon with energy less than the necessary to excite the hydrogen atom](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/601846/absorption-cross-section-for-photon-with-energy-less-than-the-necessary-to-excit)

The answer is no. The atom's center-of-mass motion can be affected, but it can't be put into an excited electronic state (with the caveats stated in the answer to your previous question).

If you want clarification or more details on an answer, please request that in comments, not by asking another almost identical question.